# Is Hong–Ou–Mandel effect reversible?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, reversibility

According to Hong–Ou–Mandel effect, two photons coming from the different ports will output by the same port with 2 photons since the cross term is canceled by a 1:1 beamsplitter. Since "light path is reversible", intuitively I think 2 photons input into beamsplitter will output one photon at each port. However, I can not find a parameterized beamsplitter that can do that? So my question is: Is Hong–Ou–Mandel effect reversible? If not, does it mean that the light path is not reversible in the quantum case?

Comment: It indeed seems to me that "light path is reversible" is not applicable here in the literal sense, but this quantum process is nevertheless reversible. I remember the output state from Hong-Ou-Mandel is an entangled two-photon state, a superposition of both photon in one port and both photon in the other port. If this entangled state is used as the input, I would expect that the output will be as expected from reversibility, one photon at each port.

Comment: It is exactly as @aystack says: an entangled two-photon state $(|2,0\rangle+|0,2\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ will transform into the separable state $|1,1\rangle$. This is commonly done with the separable photons generated from SPDC - if one's polarization is H and the other's is V, you can rotate the polarization back and forth to "create" entanglement and reverse the creation process

Comment: Ah! I see. The problem is the entanglement. A complete wave function can reproduce the reverse process. By the way, you two may leave an answer below.